Open and close 2 windows from another window in a right sequence
I have a WPF application. It has 3 windows i need to open and close in RIGHT sequence: Worker Window, Request Window, and User Messenger Window, let's name them Window1, Window2, Window3 for simplicity. Window2 has a messenger button, that opens Window3. But there is another button in Window1, that will open both Window2 and Window3.
What exactly do i want to achieve:

Click on a button in Window1
Window2 and Window3 are opened, with following z-indexes: Window1 - 1; Window2 - 2; Window3 - 3
While Window3 is opened, no actions can be done in other windows (how ShowDialog() works), same with Window2 (assuming Window3 is closed)
Whenever window is closed, they KEEP their z-indexes

What i tried:
My initial code:
                var rw = new RequestWindow(Request, false);
                var umw = new UserMessengerWindow(Request);
                rw.Show();
                umw.Topmost = true;
                umw.ShowDialog();

What really happens: it opens those windows, but Whenever Window3 is closed, Window2 goes to the back (is behind Window1).
I tried setting owner property:
                var rw = new RequestWindow(Request, false);
                var umw = new UserMessengerWindow(Request);
                rw.Owner = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<WorkerWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
                rw.Show();
                umw.Topmost = true;
                umw.ShowDialog();

Now whenever Window3 is closed, Window1 and Window2 keep their original z-indexes, but focus goes to Window1 (and it is interactable, while i want it to be not), using Focus() or Activate() on Window2 doesn't help.

"using Focus() or Activate() on Window2 doesn't help" - in WPF certain actions needs to be queued via Dispatcher, calling those directly at inappropriate time simply won't work. Try to play with dispatcher priority (second parameter) in Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => ... code to activate ... ); when you are trying to activate another window from either close event or where you close it.

Where are you from? Dagestan?

If I understand correctly what you need:
<Window x:Class="Core2024.SO.JamalShakhmurzaev.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.JamalShakhmurzaev"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
    <UniformGrid Columns="1" Background="Yellow">
        <Viewbox>
            <TextBlock Text="First" Margin="5"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox>
            <Button Content="Open Second Window" Margin="5" Padding="15 5"
                    Click="OnOpenSecondWindow"/>
        </Viewbox>
         <Viewbox>
            <Button Content="Open Third Window" Margin="5" Padding="15 5"
                    Click="OnOpenThirdWindow"/>
        </Viewbox>
   </UniformGrid>
    <x:Code>
        <![CDATA[
        private void OnOpenSecondWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window2 window2 = new Window2();
            window2.Owner = this;
            window2.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void OnOpenThirdWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window2 window2 = new Window2();
            window2.Owner = this;
            window2.Loaded += delegate
            {
                Window3 window3 = new Window3();
                window3.Owner = window2;
                window3.ShowDialog();
            };
            window2.ShowDialog();
        }
        ]]>
    </x:Code>
</Window>

<Window x:Class="Core2024.SO.JamalShakhmurzaev.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.JamalShakhmurzaev"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window2" Height="450" Width="800">
    <UniformGrid Columns="1" Background="LightGreen">
        <Viewbox>
            <TextBlock Text="Second" Margin="5"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox>
            <Button Content="Open Third Window" Margin="5" Padding="15 5"
                    Click="OnOpenThirdWindow"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </UniformGrid>
    <x:Code>
        <![CDATA[
        private void OnOpenThirdWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window3 window3 = new Window3();
            window3.Owner = this;
            window3.ShowDialog();
        }
        ]]>
    </x:Code>
</Window>


thank you so much, this is exactly what i was looking for, one little downside is that when i close all windows of the application, it keeps running (more specifically, window2). i did a little workaround by handling closed event in the main window, where i get all running windows and close them. im not a dagestani btw, but a chechen, from moscow :)

@JamalShakhmurzaev Perhaps it will be more convenient for you to use the forum https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/
